# How to set preferred width and height in fxml dynamically based on screen resolution javafx

Tags: javafx, fxml

I am new to javafx.  Is it possible to dynamically set preferred width and height in an fxml file based on screen resolution? I know how to get screen resolution and set it to stage:

```
Screen screen = Screen.getPrimary(); 
Rectangle2D bounds = screen.getVisualBounds();
stage.setWidth(bounds.getWidth());
stage.setHeight(bounds.getHeight());
```

My question is about dynamically setting prefWidth and prefHeight in fxml files.  Also I want to know if I can programmatically change property values in the fxml file, I am using scene builder.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can (sort of) do this in FXML, but not with Scene Builder (as far as I am aware). You can use a `fx:factory` attribute to get the primary screen and define it in a [`<fx:define>` block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#define_elements). Then use an [expression binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#expression_binding) to bind the `prefWidth` and `prefHeight` of the root pane to the width and height of the screen.

This looks like

MaximizedPane.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.stage.Screen?>

<StackPane xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
           prefWidth="${screen.visualBounds.width}" 
           prefHeight="${screen.visualBounds.height}" >
    <fx:define>
        <Screen fx:factory="getPrimary" fx:id="screen"/>
    </fx:define>
    <Label text="A maximized pane"/>    
</StackPane>
```

and here's a quick test harness:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MaximizedFXMLPane extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MaximizedPane.fxml")));
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

(The reason there's no way to do this with Scene Builder is that it doesn't support any mechanism for inserting `<fx:define>` blocks in your FXML, among other things.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it answers your question: this will make it easier for other users to find if they want the same information.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to mark the answer correct

Comment: Anyone can mark an answer as correct (and gain reputation by doing so). Just click on the check mark next to the answer.