# Restrict children size (of VBox) [width]

Tags: java, javafx

I need to restrict node's children size.
My parent node is a VBox. I tried to set maxWidth, but it doesn't work (wide children are out of VBox bound)

How can I restrict children size to parent? Is there any way apart from binding?

Expected behaviour: Children maxWidth is automatically the same as VBox (without setting it manually)

EDIT:

My code (fxml):

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Text?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<HBox prefWidth="800" prefHeight="400">
    <VBox maxWidth="50" style="-fx-background-color: blue;">
        <Text text="looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong one"/>
    </VBox>
</HBox>
```

Comment: same procedure as always: [mcve] please ;) it's the layout that decides how to size its children, have a look at the java doc and then choose which/how to use it

Comment: Have you tried `VBox.vgrow`? Also, take in consideration wrapping your `VBox` inside and `HBox`. Anyways, a lot of the view layer behaviours can easily be set just by modying the `fxml` and not the associated controller

Comment: @gabrielgarcia Just added some description. I only care about the width

Comment: please read the reference help page and act accoringly

Answer (score 0):

There's a `wrappingWidth` property in `javafx.scene.text.Text` which you can use to limit the size of your `Text` node.

[EDIT]
After some research, I've found some answers and documentation regarding this question:

- https://javafxpedia.com/en/tutorial/1580/fxml-and-controllers
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487258/5899042
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/41460088/5899042

Note that this approach doesn't work with SceneBuilder ([reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34487258/5899042): there's no way to do this with Scene Builder since it doesn't support any mechanism for inserting `<fx:define>` blocks in your FXML, among other things)

```xml
<HBox fx:id="hbox" prefHeight="400" prefWidth="800" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <fx:define>
            <Screen fx:factory="getPrimary" fx:id="screen" />
        </fx:define>
        <VBox fx:id="vbox" maxWidth="${screen.width}" HBox.hgrow="always"  style="-fx-background-color: blue;">
            <Text text="looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooasdasdsadasdsadasdasdooooong one" wrappingWidth="${vbox.width*0.10}"/>
        </VBox>
    </children>
</HBox>
```

This should do the trick for you, based on the links given above, but unfortunately I can't test it right now.

Comment: I can put every single node here and it will not be sized to VBox maxWidth. I don't want to set everyting manually, I'd like to have solution that enables maxWidth inheritance or something like that.

Comment: So you are looking for a generic solution for your components size? for example, the ability to set their sizes as a percentage of their parent's?

Comment: I'd like to set a maxWidth to my parent that will affect all children of my parent, e.g. they will have the same maxWidth

Comment: Ok, that's a very common asked feature when working with JavaFX. Just give me a sec and I will try to give you a working solution to your problem.